# Get string between 2 words, that contain this words inside him

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings, and i want to find in them 2 words: `START` and `END`.

`START` and `END` always come together (maybe i will have another characters between them, but if i have `START`, i will have `END` too).

Between first `START` and last `END`, i can have another couples of `START` and `END`.

I try to do with regEx source that find the first `START` and than his own `END`, and it will return the correct substring between them.

---

**here is the regEx diagram of what i need:**

(i need to get the string between the first `START` to the last `END`)

[image: regExp diagram]

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday. Why repeat the same question? If you have something to add to clarify, just edit your existing question.

Comment: Why use regex for this?

Comment: @Abhitalks no one understand me there so i wrote new one, that probably will make people understand me better.
if i just was update it, probably no one was read that update.

Comment: That is not how SO works, nor does that increases the chance of visibility. In fact it makes it liable to get closed and deleted. In order to increase user attention, you should try to improve your existing question.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the simple js indexOf and lastIndexOf instead of a regex:

```
var outerText = 'something test start something else some more test start end some more end some more'
var s = outerText.indexOf("start");
var e = outerText.lastIndexOf("end");

var innerText = outerText.substring(s+5, e);
```

Comment: but if i will have this string ` START END END`, i will not have the correct string. look at the diagram that i added

Comment: The string between the 1st START and last END is ' END ' in this case, whatelse do you want?

Answer (score 0):

First match of following regex is your string.

Regex:

```
[^start](.*)(end){1}
```

JavaScript:

```
// returns "start end "
'start start end end'.match(/[^start](.*)(end){1}/)[1]
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/qO2mS5/2

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you, this is what you want.

```
/START (.*) END/
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/vE9bQ1/1